# More than one space between two mords in gridview asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, datagridview

I am using a gridview in my asp.net web site.
I load text file into the gridview, the text file have a words wich separated by more than one space like this:  program          asp.net
my problem is that when i diplay this on my gridview, the space between program and asp.net is limited to only one space!
Any one can help me?
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace spaces with `&nbsp`, or add css class:

```
.wspace {
    white-space:pre; // or pre-wrap if you want wrapping to still work.
}
```

and then wrap content of that GridView cell into `<div class="wspace "> ... </div>`
Also, you can wrap cell content into `<pre>` which does the similar trick, but be aware of "pre" html semantics/meaning.

Comment: This work perfectly, but there are an other problem!

Comment: GridView have scroll at the right and when I add this solution the gridview don't have the have the same top alignment with the vertical scroll!